How to change the style of radial bars
I would like to improve the visual aspect of my radial graphic. I am using fake data to simulate the arrival of data from the backend of 12 or more series/labels, my code is as follows:
const chartData = {
    series: [7, 50, 25, 60, 10, 12, 5, 55, 23, 15, 85, 90],
    options: {
      chart: {
        selection: {
          enabled: false
        },
        height: 350,
        type: 'radialBar',
      },
      states: {
        active: {
          filter: {
            type: 'none'
          }
        }
      },
      plotOptions: {
        radialBar: {
          hollow: {
            size: '25%',
          },
          dataLabels: {
            name: {
              fontSize: '15px',
              show: showText
            },
            value: {
              fontSize: '15px',
            },
          },
        },
      },
      labels: ['Retomo', 'uso hold','hola', 'uso', 'llamada', 'buenas', 'usando', 'error','aceptado', 'que', 'corte', 'dos'],
    },
  };

where the following is rendered:
<div className="custom-radial-bar">
        <Title level={4}>{data.function_name}</Title>
        <ReactApexChart options={chartData.options} series={chartData.series} type="radialBar" height={chartData.options.chart.height} />
      </div>

.custom-radial-bar {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

I would like to make the 350 height bars look a little thicker but also have a gap in the center for labels and percentages. Below is a screenshot of the rendering I have achieved so far. Thank you very much in advance for any help!


You can change the width and margin of the track by adding the "track" value and giving it a width and a margin.
plotOptions: {
radialBar: {
  track: {
    width: 200,
    margin: 15,
  },
  hollow: {
    size: '25%',
  },
  dataLabels: {
    name: {
      fontSize: '15px',
      show: showText
    },
    value: {
      fontSize: '15px',
    },
  },
},


Hi Tim! Thank you very much for your answer, but I added the 'track' property and it didn't change anything. I'm looking to make the circular lines (each circle) thicker/wider.
